# How to get ALL list items regardless of view using Lists webservice

Tags: wss-3.0, list, web-services

I have a list with only one view exposed on it (default view).  That list has a filter with a field *Assigned To* = [Me] so all users logged in can only see their own list items. This list items get copied from a master list.

I have this code to get the list items from the list with only one view but it only returns the items assigned to myself (as expected).  Is there anyway to get all list items in a list regardless of the view?

```
  var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  XmlNode query = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
  XmlNode viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
  XmlNode queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");
  queryOptions.InnerXml = "<MeetingInstanceID>-1</MeetingInstanceID><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />";
  return destLists.GetListItems(listConfig.DestGuid,
                                listConfig.DestViewGuid,
                                query,
                                viewFields,
                                RowLimit,
                                queryOptions,
                                null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second node is the *viewName*, defined as:

> A string that contains the GUID for
>   the view surrounded by curly braces
>   (**{}**), which determines the view to use
>   for the default view attributes
>   represented by the *query*, *viewFields*,
>   and *rowLimit* parameters. If this
>   parameter contains an empty string,
>   the default view is used. If the view
>   GUID is supplied, the value of the
>   *query*, *viewFields*, or *rowLimit*
>   parameter overrides the equivalent
>   setting within the view. For example,
>   if the view specified by the
>   *viewFields* parameter has a row limit
>   of 100 rows but the *rowLimit* parameter
>   contains 1000, then 1,000 rows are
>   returned in the response.

Source: [MSDN - Lists.GetListItems Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx)

Since you're passing empty strings for *query*, *viewFields*, and *rowLimit*, you're getting the default view, exactly as defined in the list.

To override the *Assigned To = [Me]*, you'll have to write the *query* to have different parameters. The referenced page gives examples of how to write the query XML.

Comment: @Jim, thanks, threw a custom query in the `query` node and got all the items :)

Comment: Excellent!!!! Glad to have helped!